# Customize month name in Datepicker Ng bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to customize the Month name, which is currently abbreviated to show the full name

It currently looks like this:

[image: month name abbreviated]

and I wish it to be like this: 
[image: monthe name full]

And I would also like to remove the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You has an example in [Internationalization of datepickers](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#i18n)

You create a `CustomDatepickerI18n` that extends NgbDatepickerI18n with the functions:

```
  getWeekdayLabel(weekday: number): string 
  getWeekLabel(): string 
  getMonthShortName(month: number): string 
  getMonthFullName(month: number): string 
  getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string
```

And use as provider in your module (or in your component)

```
providers:
      [{provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: CustomDatepickerI18n}]
```